# Where is the fade inactive geometry slider?

Tags: modifiers, 3d-view, geometry

I am looking for the fade inactive geometry slider, but this is what the viewport looks like for me: (blender 3.2)

[image]

The tutorial I was watching had those options:

[image]

Anyone knows where I can find the slider for the Fade Inactive Geometry?

(and I'm also wondering why my viewport overlays has so much fewer options)

Comment: The *Fade Inactive Geometry* overlay option is only visible when the model is in *Edit* mode. Your model is most likely in *Object* mode. Close the menu, press the TAB key to enter *Edit* mode, then open the dropdown menu again and you should see the option.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! I was stuck for so long, this was exactly what I was looking for. Really appreciated!